# Handling an interrupt while being on kernel

Tags: kernel, interrupt

I know how interrupt handling works (switching mode, saving registers, changing stack ...). However, I am curious, what if an interrupt happens while we are still in kernel mode, and not in user mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same. However if we are processing an interrupt then possibly nothing, or nothing until we finish.

What we do in all cases:

- unconditionally save mode, and set mode to supervisor mode (done by hardware. Triggered by interrupt)
- unconditionally save state and switch stack
- run interrupt code
- unconditionally switch stack back, restore state and restore mode

The phrase "set mode to supervisor mode", could be read as any of these:

- ensure that mode is supervisor mode.
- write a one into the S bit of the status register

## Interrupting an interrupt

There are possibly multiple (but finite) interrupt priority levels. There will be a stack for each level. An interrupt can only be interrupted by a higher priority of interrupt. Lower priority interrupts, can be blocked by higher priority. This solves most of the problems, not stacks can't get corrupted.

However lower priority interrupts can be blocked (including user processes. These are the lowest interrupt priority). Therefore,
It is important to ensure that interrupts are fast (not much code), especially for higher priority interrupts: Get the job done and exit, have a lower priority interrupt (such as a user process) do the bit that takes time.

## Stacks

A kernel can use the same stack as the process, when a process calls into the kernel (synchronise call: using a syscall in the code of a program).

A kernel will also have a stack for each interrupt priority level. See section on interrupting an interrupt.

Comment: Can you give details ? suppose we detect an interruption ; then we check the S bit in SR (status register) ; if it's 0 , then we are on user mode ,we'll switch mode , save registers , change stack ... if not what happens ?

Comment: I think that your confusion is in thinking that there is a conditional/selection. There is not.

Comment: okey thanks for putting details ! but suppose we are on user mode , theres an interrupt so we switch to user do what you said and before restoring mode another interruption take place ? I think there will bugs ( because for example in such case you can't switch stack because there only one kernel stack per process , and we are already in that one ?)

Comment: Because the question is still there ! when second interruption occur how we will be sure that it wont overwrite the first interruption state/registers ? and like i said in the second interr , you CANT switch the stack , because theres only one kernel stack !

Comment: I have added some clarity. Does it answer what happens when an interrupt interrupts an interrupt? Is this what you need? Why do you think there is one kernel stack? There can be zero (shared with process), or one per interrupt priority level (if you have interrupts (this is more normal)).

Comment: The "done by hardware" bit depends on the architecture, it doesn't have to be always that way.

Comment: @vonbrand How? You can't enter supervisor mode from user mode, except via syscall or interrupt. So you could have a user-mode interrupt. Is this what you are eluding to?